# How to make this javascript start at a certain time?

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript below:
But what I want to do is make it so that it starts at 7:30am Every morning! I dont know if its possible, but if you know how please share! Thanks if you can!

```
 <script>

 var timer;
 var stop;

 function startCount()
 {
      stop = false;
      timer = setInterval(count,1);
 }
 function stopCount()
 {
      stop = true;
 }
 function count()
 {
      if(stop == false)
          {
           var el = document.getElementById('counter');
           var currentNumber = parseFloat(el.innerHTML);
           el.innerHTML = currentNumber+0.00000003831417624521;
      }
 }
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>

 <div id="counter">0</div>

 <input type="button" value="reset" id="reset" onclick="document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = 0;" />
 <input type="button" value="start" id="start" onclick="startCount();" />
 <input type="button" value="stop" id="stop" onclick="stopCount();" />
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

The only way to make Javascript start at something like 7:30 AM every morning is if a user has the page up already.

If that's the case, and for this example I'm going to assume that it is the case, when a user loads the page, you would initially have javascript check the current time and calculate how many seconds are between now and 7:30AM.

From there, you would initiate a setTimeout that will run after the calculated number of seconds - setTimeout works on milliseconds, so the setTimeout argument would be: number of seconds * 1000.

Answer (score 0):

1. Count milis left to 7:30
2. Call setTimeout(function_you_want_to_call, timeLeft)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout(function checkTime() {
    var now = new Date;
     if ( now.getHours() >= 7 && now.getMinutes() >= 30 ) {
        // run special code here
     } else {
        setTimeout(checkTime, 10);
     } 
}, 10);
```

This assumes you want to run this code anytime after 7:30am.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply perform a time check, if it doesn't match, calculate the difference and set a callback. Because timing measurement is not very accurate, you might want to call back to some time earlier to take a another measurement.

```
function runEveryDay(func, timeToRun, lastRun) {
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    var timeOfDay = now % 86400;
    if (timeOfDay - timeToRun < 5000 && now - lastRun > 83200) {
        setTimeout((function (func, timeToRun, lastRun) {
            return function () {
                runEveryDay(func, timeToRun, lastRun);
            };
        })(fun, timeToRun, now), 83200);
        func();
    } else {
        setTimeout((function (func, timeToRun, lastRun) {
            return function () {
                runEveryDay(func, timeToRun, lastRun);
            };
        })(fun, timeToRun, lastRun), (timeToRun - now) * 0.95 + 1000);
    }
}
```

The values 5000, 83200, 0.95 and 1000 should be adjusted to fit your precision and accuracy needs.

Comment: That's seriously overcomplicated.